# VB.net : How to protect a global variable from being modified inside a sub (ByVal, ByRef : not applicable)

Tags: vb.net

I have a global variable X in an winform application.

The variable X is used in different forms inside the application and I don't want it to be modified. It's not used as a parameter in the functions... so ByRef, or ByVal are not applicable.

It's used like that:

Declaration

```
dim X as whatever;
dim Y as whatever;

private sub SubExample(A as object)
    'Do some staff
    'Locally modifiy X
     X = something else;
end sub
```

Main program

```
call SubExample(Y);
'After this, X should still have its original value
```

Any idea please ?

Comment: if you don't want to change X value why you assigned new value.
if it's constant use `Const X as whatever = value`

Comment: this looks to me as constant variable, but u want this functionality temporarily, so why not write a line after calling SuExample(Y) that sets the value back to the original ?

Comment: @Al-3sli : the idea is to avoid changing it by mistake in the code.

Comment: if you declare X as const it will never change and will not allow you to change it, it will give an error if you try.

Comment: **Don't use global variables**. Period, I can't stress this more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't *protect* a global variable (unless it has to be assigned only once, in that case it can be `Const`). By [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable) it's global so it's visibile by all classes.

I would avoid them every time it's possible because of that: you can't restrict their access to who really has to use it (as you found by yourself) and **they couple all classes use them**. Main problems I see with them are:

- **Testing**: because they couple many (all?) classes they make code testing pretty hard. You can't really isolate a class or sub-system for testing.
- **Concurrency**: they're free accessed by everything in any thread then you'll have concurrency issues and you'll need to make them thread-safe. A variable in VB.NET can be thread-safe (at least atomic read/write) only for primitive types.
- **Access**: as you saw you can't restrict access to them. Even if you make them global properties you can just make them read-only but somewhere a write function/setter must exist (unless you're using them for singleton pattern or for other - few - corner cases).
- **Maintenability**: your code will be harder to understand because implications won't be obvious and *local*.

What you can do to replace them with something more "safe"?

- If you put them in a global class with `Shared` members just remove `Shared` and make them instance members. If they're in a `Module` just move them to a `Class`.
- Make your class [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) (I would use a method instead of simple property to make this more obvious). This may or not be your case, you may simply create your object in your startup method.
- Add a public property in each form will need them and when you create your form just set this property to class you previously created. According to effective implementation this may be or not a Context Object pattern.

If you have multiple sets of global variables (and each set has different *users*) you may need to create multiple classes (one class for each set of variables).

This is a pretty general method to quickly replace global variables, better way implies some deeper refactoring to make your code more *OOP-ish* but I can't say without a more complete view of your code.

Answer (score 0):

As a low-tech solution, I would recommend using an unambiguous name like

```
Dim READONLY_X
```

as the name of your global variable. Then you are less likely to forget that you should not be writing a new value to it.  When you feel the temptation to write the line:

```
READONLY_X = 2
```

it should ring an alarm bell. Wrapping inside getter functions etc (without the formalism of a class) seems like a kluge. But that's just an opinion.

As was said before, global variables are a pain; think carefully about the scope you want them to have, and whether there isn't another solution...